# how to convert array value and get length in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
var category_arr = ["14seatervan", "Hatchback", "Sedan"];

var i, s, caArray = category_arr,
  len = caArray.length;


for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {

  alert(len);
}
```

if I alert the `length` I got a this issue

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

How to get this variable length and convert comma values into array value using jquery. Kindly help me

Comment: What is the issue here? It works fine https://jsfiddle.net/8o5dyee1/

Comment: Sorry if my  var category_arr =["14seatervan","Hatchback","Sedan"];
  like this  var category_arr =["14seatervan,Hatchback,Sedan"];

Comment: How can i get length

Comment: @MeenaNarayanan That is not a valid `array`

Comment: in second variat you has array with one element -"14seatervan,Hatchback,Sedan" . It is string

Comment: It worked fine for me-
Where did you try to run the script?

Comment: its working sry for my mistake